# How to copy URL using PHP or JS only last part of domain like post name

Tags: javascript, php, html, url

How to copy URL using PHP or JavaScript. I only want last part of URL like from this URL "https://stackoverflow.com/questions" i need "questions" only part to be shown in Text box

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the full URL in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6768793/get-the-full-url-in-php)

Comment: I think you should choose PHP or javascript and not ask on both languages. Also what do you mean by "shown in Text box" ?

Comment: I want it in PHP and want show output in textarea

Comment: You just have to get a hold on the QueryString or URL that comes in, then its a matter of parsing that string... that could be achieved in both language easilly.

Answer (score 1):

`parse_url()` is your friend for PHP. See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript you can get it by:

```
window.location.pathname
```

This shows the string `/question` if the URL is:

`https://stackoverflow.com/questions`

Here is an example of this site:

```js
const URL = window.location.pathname;

console.log(URL);
```

Comment: will you plz tell me how can i get output of it? can i store it in variable?

Comment: one more example plz with variable Thank you for guidance.

Comment: You can store it in a variable using (const, var, let). Then you can access this variable later again and use it in a different location. Like in the console.log example.

Comment: ok, thank you but i am new i do not know how to do that that's why wrote here for help.